# image in safari browser is deformed

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

i have a image in a **li** tag.my image in firefox and chrome is Ok and shown as follows:

[image]

but in safari browser in IOS and macOS it's deformed:

[image]

this is my code:

```
<div class="colors">
        <ul id="marker" class="d-flex flex-wrap ps-0 mx-3">
        <li class="d-flex justify-content-center me-1 mt-1 me-md-2 mt-md-2 ms-xxl-4" id="marker-118" style="border:1px #FFD600 solid;width: 60px;height: 60px;2.jpg">
         <img loading="lazy" style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="changeImage(this);" onmouseleave="changeImageLeave(this);" onclick="changeProduct('1164','118','0','0','FA','3250');changeColor('mm');" src="/1164/thumbnail/size_100/2.jpg">
        </li>
        </ul> </div>
```

actually i want to show image in **li** as centered horizental similar chrome and firefox.(first image top photo)

Comment: remove 2.jpg from style inside li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set this for image and it was ok:

```
object-fit: contain;
```